# AFrame Firefox Oculus crash: How to Debug

Tags: firefox, aframe, webvr, oculus

We implement an A-Frame webapplication with a lot of a-entities and animations. Everything works fine on the browser or in the mobile VR-Mode with a Daydream.

Entering the VR-Mode in Firefox WebVR also works and everything is fine with the Oculus Rift. But after a few interactions, changing scenes triggering interactions etc. the Oculus started to hang up, the images stutter in the oculus and in Firefox Browser. Sometimes the stuttering starts directly after entering the VR-Mode...

There are no errors in the browser developer console. The Oculus Diagnostics/OculusServiceLogs includes Warnings with:

```
{WARNING} [ApplicationPackage] App C_ProgramFiles_MozillaFirefox_firefox has exited with error: 1
```

or that the Firefox Process has disconnected.

The analyze by the Firefox Performance Tool seems to be normal. But the CPU usage doesnt get idle anymore and one core is at 100%.

Also simple examples from aframe.io leads to the same behaviour.

I have no idea anymore how to debug this environment. Perhaps anyone got the same behaviour or ideas how to solve.

Comment: When you say "crash", do you mean that the Firefox process actually dies? If not, it sounds like you're running into this recent performance bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1514417

Comment: The process doesnt die. Less than 1 FPS describes out behaviour very good. Thanks for the hint.